# Nginx default vhost config not working

Tags: nginx, php

Setting up nginx on an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server. All gone swimmingly apart from this config file does not allow me to access files under the www/ with the domain like I should be able to.

Here's my file:

```
server {
    listen   80;


    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name beta.davidheward.com;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
          root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    location ~ .+\.php$ {
            #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            # With php5-fpm:
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
    }
```

}

Any ideas why this would be would be massively appreciated. I am trying to hit beta.davidheward.com/info.php

Many thanks.

Comment: What's in the error log?

Answer (score 0):

(check your DNS too, you need to add the subdomain `A entry` there)

```
listen   80;
```

should be:

```
listen   your_full_ip;  // xxx.xxx.xx.xx (dont need to add the port if is the port 80)
```

these:

```
location ~ .+\.php$ {
```

into these:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
```

move these 2 lines to the server block:
 fastcgi_index index.php;
 include fastcgi_params;

put the server block in order:

```
server_name beta.davidheward.com;
listen   your_full_ip;
index index.php index.html index.htm;
root /usr/share/nginx/www;
```

hope it helps. Do a nginx restart when u are done!